# Gelfands three books as a replacement for a precalculus book?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I own gelfand’s algebra, functions and graphs, and was going to combine his trigonometry book with Lang’s basic math. However, Gelfand’s algebra does not seem to go over logarithms, which as far as I know, is pre calculus.

I thought logarithms were introduced in algebra, so why does his book not include it? I am worried that his books aren’t enough to prepare me for Calc 1

Comment: I recommend looking at several different books simultaneously when learning math. Gelfand's books are too good to avoid just because they don't discuss a certain topic.

Comment: Lee if you'd like to learn logarithms right now I'll give you a series of exercises. Let $b > 1$. If $x > 0$, then $\log_b(x)$ is defined to be the number $y$ such that $b^y = x$. (A better name might be "the exponent from $b$ to $x$." Now suppose that $M, N > 0$. Prove: 1) $\log_b(b^M) = M$. 2) $b^{\log_b(M)} = M$. 3) $\log_b(MN) = \log_b(M) + \log_b(N)$. 4) $\log_b(M/N) = \log_b(M) - \log_b(N)$. 5) If $c > 1$, then $\log_c(M) = \log_b(M)/\log_b(c)$.

Comment: So should I add on a pre calculus book then? Or additional algebra books? I guess my question is, what subject area are logarithms introduced in? Algebra?

Comment: Personally I think [Cohen](https://www.amazon.com/Precalculus-David-Cohen/dp/0840069421)'s precalculus book is pretty good. I bet the AoPS book is good too (but be prepared to encounter very challenging Olympiad level problems).

Comment: Just to remark that logarithms appear in the AoPS intermediate algebra book, rather than in the precalc book as you might expect.

Comment: @littleO I taught the AoPS precalculus course. It does not even cover logs and exponentials and concentrates on trigonometry, complex numbers, matrices, and linear algebra concepts. It's not a great recommendation for this purpose. Cohen's book is a standard university-level precalculus course.

Comment: Perhaps I’ll use gelfands algbera and then AOPS intermediate algebra. I also didn’t know cohens was standard